# Get the username from the session in ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I use this code to store the loged in username in the session

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ContactFound.ContaLogin, model.RememberMe);
```

Now, how can I get this username once the user is logged in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

When you are in a Controller:

```
this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, but when I used your code I had this error
'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I suppose you are in a class implementing Controller. So I edited my answer to reflect your context.

Comment: @As per my knowledge it should work still we are define in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```